# Errors accessing MultiIndex in DataFrame from spreadsheet

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

This is difficult to pin down, but it seems like I cannot use a multiindex in a dataframe read from a spreadsheet with `pandas.read_excel`.   I've placed all files in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/cswarth/9b4c33d902e9752c66a4)

```
df = pd.read_excel('small.xlsx')
df.set_index(['qrsid','locus'], inplace=True)
print(('dkdkd', 'kdkd') in df.index)
```

Produces an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mindex.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(('dkdkd', 'kdkd') in df.index)
  File "/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 947, in __contains__
    self.get_loc(key)
  File "/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 1538, in get_loc
    if lead_key else (0, len(self)))
  File "/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 1444, in slice_locs
    return super(MultiIndex, self).slice_locs(start, end, step, kind=kind)
  File "/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2879, in slice_locs
    start_slice = self.get_slice_bound(start, 'left', kind)
  File "/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 1415, in get_slice_bound
    return self._partial_tup_index(label, side=side)
  File "/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 1460, in _partial_tup_index
    raise TypeError('Level type mismatch: %s' % lab)
TypeError: Level type mismatch: dkdkd
```

A similar dataframe with multi-index created from pandas primitives works fine,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'qrsid':['qb210', 'qb210', 'qb210', 'qb210', 'qb210'],
                'locus':['gag','gag','gag','gag','gag'],
                'dpi': [ 800, 1002, 2291, 4444, 212]})
df.set_index(['qrsid','locus'], inplace=True)
print(('dkdkd', 'kdkd') in df.index)
```

I can't figure out what is different between the two dataframes.  Both have the same `df.dtypes`.  `df.index` on both look identical.  Can anyone tell me why accessing the index on the first one fails?

---

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python -c 'import pandas; print pandas.__version__'
0.18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why this happens now. I printed out types being compared in `pandas.indexes.base.Index.is_type_compatible`

```
is_type_compatible: kind=string   inferred_type=unicode
```

So apparently `pandas.read_excel()` is reading strings as unicode and those are type-incompatible with simple 'strings'.

The indexing error message here could be A LOT more informative.  Just telling me 'Level type mismatch' provides almost no useful information.